# How to cast nested list to matrix like or tabular like object?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have nested list data that needed to be in desired output representation, either matrix like object or just directly export these nested list as csv file. I tried several general approach to do this task, but exporting nested list is not going well, so I am looking for the solution that casting nested list to matrix like or tabular like object to hold data in desired way. Maybe I could hold nested list data in data.table, but not quite sure about this. Can anyone tell me how to do this sort of manipulation easily ? How can I achieve clean, well structured data representation for nested list data ? Any idea ? Thanks a lot

mini example :

output of custom function:

```
AcceptedList <- list(
  A_accepted = data.frame(pos.start=c(1,6,16), pos.stop=c(4,12,23), pos.ID=c("A1","A2","A3"), pos.score=c(11,8,13)),
  B_accepted = data.frame(pos.start=c(7,19,31), pos.stop=c(13,28,43), pos.ID=c("B3","B6","B7"), pos.score=c(12,5,7)),
  C_accepted = data.frame(pos.start=c(5,21,36), pos.stop=c(11,29,42), pos.ID=c("C2","C4","C9"), pos.score=c(7,13,9))
)

RejectedList <- list(
  A_rejected = data.frame(pos.start=c(6,25,40), pos.stop=c(12,33,49), pos.ID=c("A2","A5","A8"), pos.score=c(8,4,7)),
  B_rejected = data.frame(pos.start=c(15,19,47), pos.stop=c(18,28,55), pos.ID=c("B4","B6","B9"), pos.score=c(10,5,14)),
  C_rejected = data.frame(pos.start=c(13,21,36,53), pos.stop=c(19,29,42,67), pos.ID=c("C3","C4","C9","C12"), pos.score=c(4,13,9,17))
)
```

so I implement this function to further manipulate output one more step :

```
func <- function(mlist, threshold) {
  res <- lapply(mlist, function(x) {
    splt <- split(x, ifelse(x$pos.score >= threshold, "up", "down"))
  })
  return(res)
}

#example
.res_accepted <- func(AcceptedList, 9)
.res_rejected <- func(RejectedList, 9)
```

I have hard time how to case nested list `.res_accepted, .res_rejected` as matrix like object. Ideally exporting nested list as csv file is highly expected, but I failed to export them in desired way. How can I make this happen ?

ultimately, desired list of csv files with desired named as follows:

```
A_accepted_up.csv
A_accepted_down.csv
A_rejected_up.csv
A_rejected_down.csv
B_accepted_up.csv
B_accepted_down.csv
B_rejected_up.csv
B_rejected_down.csv
C_accepted_up.csv
C_accepted_down.csv
C_rejected_up.csv
C_rejected_down.csv
```

The point is, nested list returned by my custom functions, so I intend to either directly export them or cast them into matrix like object as well. Any idea for this sort of manipulation ? Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns a data.frame `DF` of the data.  No packages are used.

```
both <- do.call("rbind", c(AcceptedList, RejectedList))
cn <- c("letter", "accepted", "seq")
DF <- cbind(
         read.table(text = chartr("_", ".", rownames(both)), sep = ".", col.names = cn), 
         both)
DF <- transform(DF, updown = ifelse(pos.score > 8, "up", "down"))
```

giving:

```
> DF
             letter accepted seq pos.start pos.stop pos.ID pos.score updown
A_accepted.1      A accepted   1         1        4     A1        11     up
A_accepted.2      A accepted   2         6       12     A2         8   down
A_accepted.3      A accepted   3        16       23     A3        13     up
B_accepted.1      B accepted   1         7       13     B3        12     up
B_accepted.2      B accepted   2        19       28     B6         5   down
B_accepted.3      B accepted   3        31       43     B7         7   down
C_accepted.1      C accepted   1         5       11     C2         7   down
C_accepted.2      C accepted   2        21       29     C4        13     up
C_accepted.3      C accepted   3        36       42     C9         9     up
A_rejected.1      A rejected   1         6       12     A2         8   down
A_rejected.2      A rejected   2        25       33     A5         4   down
A_rejected.3      A rejected   3        40       49     A8         7   down
B_rejected.1      B rejected   1        15       18     B4        10     up
B_rejected.2      B rejected   2        19       28     B6         5   down
B_rejected.3      B rejected   3        47       55     B9        14     up
C_rejected.1      C rejected   1        13       19     C3         4   down
C_rejected.2      C rejected   2        21       29     C4        13     up
C_rejected.3      C rejected   3        36       42     C9         9     up
C_rejected.4      C rejected   4        53       67    C12        17     up
```

This will write `DF` out in separate files:

```
junk <- by(DF, DF[c("letter", "accepted", "updown")], 
      function(x) write.csv(x[-(1:3)], 
       sprintf("%s_%s_%s.csv", x$letter[1], x$accepted[1], x$updown[1])))
```

or this will write out the data frames in `.res_accepted` -- `.res_rejected` could be handled similarly:

```
junk <- lapply(names(.res_accepted), function(nm) 
  mapply(write.csv, 
            .res_accepted[[nm]], 
            paste0(nm, "_", names(.res_accepted[[nm]]), ".csv")))
```

**Note:** The poster changed the data after this answer already had appeared.  The output above corresponds to the original data; however, it should also work for the revised data.  The original data was:

```
AcceptedList <- 
structure(list(foo_accepted = structure(list(pos.start = c(1, 
6, 16), pos.stop = c(4, 12, 23), pos.ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3"), class = "factor"), pos.score = c(11, 8, 13)), .Names = c("pos.start", 
"pos.stop", "pos.ID", "pos.score"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), 
    bar_accepted = structure(list(pos.start = c(7, 19, 31), pos.stop = c(13, 
    28, 43), pos.ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("B3", "B6", "B7"
    ), class = "factor"), pos.score = c(12, 5, 7)), .Names = c("pos.start", 
    "pos.stop", "pos.ID", "pos.score"), row.names = c(NA, -3L
    ), class = "data.frame"), cat_accepted = structure(list(pos.start = c(5, 
    21, 36), pos.stop = c(11, 29, 42), pos.ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("C2", 
    "C4", "C9"), class = "factor"), pos.score = c(7, 13, 9)), .Names = c("pos.start", 
    "pos.stop", "pos.ID", "pos.score"), row.names = c(NA, -3L
    ), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("foo_accepted", "bar_accepted", 
"cat_accepted"))

RejectedList <- 
structure(list(foo_rejected = structure(list(pos.start = c(6, 
25, 40), pos.stop = c(12, 33, 49), pos.ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A2", 
"A5", "A8"), class = "factor"), pos.score = c(8, 4, 7)), .Names = c("pos.start", 
"pos.stop", "pos.ID", "pos.score"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), 
    bar_rejected = structure(list(pos.start = c(15, 19, 47), 
        pos.stop = c(18, 28, 55), pos.ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("B4", 
        "B6", "B9"), class = "factor"), pos.score = c(10, 5, 
        14)), .Names = c("pos.start", "pos.stop", "pos.ID", "pos.score"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), cat_rejected = structure(list(
        pos.start = c(13, 21, 36, 53), pos.stop = c(19, 29, 42, 
        67), pos.ID = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("C12", 
        "C3", "C4", "C9"), class = "factor"), pos.score = c(4, 
        13, 9, 17)), .Names = c("pos.start", "pos.stop", "pos.ID", 
    "pos.score"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")), 
.Names = c("foo_rejected", 
"bar_rejected", "cat_rejected"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is just what I want to do. many thanks :)

Comment: I figured out the role of by. Thanks again for your contribution :)